# Cannot set javafx.scene.control.TextField to field 'user'

Tags: java, javafx, textfield, fxml

What is the difference between the passwordfield above and the textfield below?
(refering to fxml)

Why is one allowed and the other not?

```
@FXML
private PasswordField login;

@FXML 
private TextArea userlogin;
```

Link to fxml
https://i.stack.imgur.com/essR9.jpg

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Please post the code in the question, instead of linking to it

Comment: please see your imports, imports must 'import javafx.scene.control...'

Answer (score 2):

In your code you use TextArea, in your fxml you use TextField.

Change

```
@FXML
private TextArea userLogin;
```

to

```
@FXML
private TextField userLogin;
```

and you should be fine?